# How to align center of one element with baseline of another in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

A simple question: how do I align the center of one element with the baseline of another? Here's an example:

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span>
            <svg version="1.1"
                 baseProfile="full"
                 viewBox="0 0 300 300"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                <rect x=0 y=0 width="300" height="300" fill="red" />

                <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="80" fill="green" />

                <line x1="0" y1="150" x2="300" y2="150" stroke="black"/>

            </svg>

            <i>Something good text</i>
</span>
```

I want the center of the svg (marked by the black line) to be aligned with the baseline of the text. Of course, it may be possible to this with hardcoded negative margins or other fixed pixel offsets, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: the issue is that the baseline of the SVG is its bottom edge and not the text so technically the browser cannot identify the baseline your are defining

Comment: Could you tell us more about what the constraints are? What are the known / fixed variables? Do you know the height of the SVG? Can your text be multiline or always single line? ...

Comment: Text is single line, height of SVG is known. Of course, if there is a solution with unknown height I'd also be interested.

Comment: @Temani Afif: I am not asking about the baseline of the svg. I want to align the centre of the svg with the baseline of the "Something good text" text, which has a defined baseline

Comment: and that text is manually placed (using x/y) inside the SVG so there is no way to know that manual position (the baseline you want) from the outside because it won't define the baseline of the SVG like text can do with other elements. That's why I said *the issue is that the baseline of the SVG is its bottom edge and not the text*

Comment: @TemaniAfif maybe it's not that clear from the example, but I am *not* talking about the text *inside* the svg. I simply want to align the *center* of the svg with the *baseline of the text next to the svg* (not the one inside!).

Comment: I removed the text from the svg to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2):

No need flexbox for this:

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-0.5ex);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"
                 baseProfile="full"
                 viewBox="0 0 300 300"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect x=0 y=0 width="300" height="300" fill="red" />
     <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="80" fill="green" />
     <line x1="0" y1="150" x2="300" y2="150" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
<i>Something good text</i>
```

> middle
>
> Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline **plus half the x-height** of the parent. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</sup>

So I rectify the *plus half the x-height* with a translation using minus *half the x-height*